# custom image uploading from frontend in magento code does not work

Tags: magento

i've problem in uploading images in my custom module in magento..

i used core php ccoding for this purpose but magento is not uploading image..

i used same code to upload file in my local xampp.
but that code is not working on my server..

i also use this code but it also not working....

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'customer_documents'.DS; //desitnation directory
  $fname = $_FILES['docname']['name']; //file name
  $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('docname'); //load class
  $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc','pdf','txt','docx')); //Allowed extension for file
  $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true); //for creating the directory if not exists
  $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); //if true, uploaded file's name will be changed, if file with the same name already exists directory.
  $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
  $uploader->save($path,$fname); //save the file on the specified path
```

Comment: What happens? what errors do you get?

Comment: image was not uploading.. but now my problem has solved.. the error is... i was forget to include magento file uploader.php

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that the question shows as complete/answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added this line in my code and it's working..

```
<?php require_once ("lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php");?>
```

after this write this code

```
<?php
$path = Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'customer_documents'.DS; //desitnation directory
  $fname = $_FILES['docname']['name']; //file name
  $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('docname'); //load class
  $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc','pdf','txt','docx')); //Allowed extension for file
  $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true); //for creating the directory if not exists
  $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); //if true, uploaded file's name will be changed, if file with the same name already exists directory.
  $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
  $uploader->save($path,$fname); //save the file on the specified path
?>
```

Comment: Where to write this code ? What would be its path, What would be variable/inputs name of file in form ?? Please edit it as answer is not clear